# Excel: Multiple rows with the same ID, add column for different variables

Tags: excel

I have a file excel (simplified below) with multiple rows with the same ID, the reson why i have multiple rows is because some field are different but i need only one row for each ID.

I have tried to solve this problem using transpose but it does not take into account when the ID is the same, also i have tried so create an IF in each column but it does not work.
Example:

[image]

Result:

[image]

I solved the problem using this macro:

```
  Sub Consolidate_Rows()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xRows As Long
Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
On Error Resume Next
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Select Range:", "Kutools For Excel", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
Set xRg = Range(Intersect(xRg, ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Address)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
xRows = xRg.Rows.Count
For I = xRows To 2 Step -1
For J = 1 To I - 1
If xRg(I, 1).Value = xRg(J, 1).Value And J <> I Then
For K = 2 To xRg.Columns.Count
If xRg(J, K).Value <> "" Then
If xRg(I, K).Value = "" Then
xRg(I, K) = xRg(J, K).Value
Else
xRg(I, K) = xRg(I, K).Value & "," & xRg(J, K).Value
End If
End If
Next
xRg(J, 1).EntireRow.Delete
I = I - 1
J = J - 1
End If
Next
Next
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you have tried to solve this problem. Perhaps take a look at the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have updated my request

Comment: @Stefano should be simple with `Power Query`

Comment: @Stefano are you easy with `Power Query` solution or are you looking for `Excel Formula` Solution only. With Power Query, it will be better i believe, since its one time process, dynamic, and whenever a new data is added, its gets updated automatically by a quick refresh on the imported table.

Comment: I am looking for the easiest solution, unfortunately i don't know how to write a query from 0

Comment: @Stefano alright i am sharing the solution in `Answer`

Comment: i have solved the problem using this VBA macro, using this i should perform another step which is comma delimitation. do you think this is a good solution?

Comment: Yes, I think any solution is good as long as you understand, i am updating the solution with both `Power Query` and `Excel Formula`

Comment: Can any of the columns have multiple entries, or might it only be the last column?

Comment: @Stefano I assume you are not well versed with `VBA` since the code you took from ExtendOffice, hence i will highly suggest you to use `Power Query`, please follow the steps as i have mentioned below in answer and it will be pretty quick easy and you will understand it.

Comment: @Stefano if that resolves your query then you can accept it as an answer/vote up the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please refer this, you can easily transform the data, as you are expecting using both `Excel Formula` as well as using `Power Query`**

**Approach Using Excel Formula** **--> Applicable to Excel 2021 & O365 Users**

**Formula used in cell A15**

```
=UNIQUE(A2:E5)
```

**Formula used in cell F15**

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($F$2:$F$5,A15=$A$2:$A$5))
```

[image: SOLUTION_USING_FORMULA]

**Approach Using Power Query**

- **Select the data and from Data Tab, Under Get & Transform Data Group, Click From Table/Range**
- **On Clicking above you shall be prompted with Create Table window, click the check box on my table as headers and press ok**
- **On doing above you shall be directed to power query editor**
- **Select the first 5 columns by holding down the shift key and press Group By from Home Tab, under Transform group or From Transform tab**
- **A new window opens as shown below, enter the new column name as All, and the Operation will All Rows press Ok**

[image: GROUP BY]

- **Next from Add Column Tab --> Click Custom Column and enter the below in custom column formula, and name new column name as Provincia**

  Table.Column([All],"Provincia")

[image: CUSTOM_COLUMN]

- **Click on the dropdown from the Provincia column and select extract values, press Ok**

[image: Extract_Rows_1]
[image: Extract_Rows_2]

- **Now again select the column Provincia and Click on Split Column From Home Tab, delimiter is comma, split at each occurrence of the delimiter and press ok, refer the image below**

[image: SPLIT_COLUMN]

- **Once the column is split it shall show like below, and now remove the unwanted column All**

[image: AFTER_SPLIT]

- **Last but not least from Home Tab, Click Close & Load To**

[image: Close & Load To]

- **From Import Data Window --> Select Table, you can check Existing worksheet or New worksheet, if checking Existing worksheet then select the cell where you want to place the data**

[image: Import_Data]

- **Expected Output as desired, this is one time process, and whenever you add new data just refresh the imported data, it updated within in few, you are not hardcoding anything here with just few simple steps, its done,**

[image: USING_POWER_QUERY]

You can also paste this M-Language only change the Table Name as per your workbook

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ID", "Targa", "Modello", "Lordo Chiusura", "Lordo Apertura"}, {{"All", each _, type table [ID=text, Targa=text, Modello=text, Lordo Chiusura=text, Lordo Apertura=text, Provincia=text]}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Provincia", each Table.Column([All],"Provincia")),
#"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Provincia", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Provincia", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Provincia.1", "Provincia.2", "Provincia.3", "Provincia.4"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"All"})
in
#"Removed Columns"
```